# How to create sub-assumptions within an assumption chunk and be able to reference them via labels?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems

I currently am trying to create an Assumption with 4 parts to it. I have first declared the assumptions chunk, then enumerated A,B,C, and D within. I am then trying to create reference labels for them. The sample code is as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\begin{document}
\begin{assumption}[The Assumptions]\label{assumption1}
We have the following four assumptions. 

\begin{enumerate}[label={}]
\item \textbf{Part A:}
    Assumption B goes here
\item \textbf{Part B:}
    Assumption B goes here
\item \textbf{Part C:}
    Assumption C goes here
\item \textbf{Part D:}
    Assumption D goes here
\end{enumerate}

\end{assumption}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to be able to put labels into each of the items of the `enumerate` chunk, but am having difficulties there. I am wondering if there is a way to do this with what I have above, or if there is a better way to go about things. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}

\begin{document}
\begin{assumption}[The Assumptions]\label{assumption1}
We have the following four assumptions. 

\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{Part~\Alph*:}}, ref={assumption~\Alph*}]
\item \label{assump-A}%
    Assumption A goes here
\item \label{assump-B}%
    Assumption B goes here
\item \label{assump-C}%
    Assumption C goes here
\item \label{assump-D}%
    Assumption D goes here
\end{enumerate}

\end{assumption}

This is a reference to \ref{assump-B}. Now to \ref{assump-A}, etc.
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

If you want the references to be prefixed by the assumption number (here, 1 since there is only one `\begin{assumption}`), use:

```latex
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{Part~\Alph*:}},
  ref={assumption~\theassumption.\Alph*}]
```

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Thank you! I am also wondering if there is perhaps a way to retain the top-level number, i.e., have Assumption 1A, Assumption 1B, etc. Is there an easy way to do this too? Thanks.

Comment: It's in my edit. :-)

Comment: Wow thank you!! This is awesome.

Comment: My pleasure. :-)